# run a programm with timeout sending multiple signals in different times

Tags: timeout

i need to run a programm with timeout with multiple time limits and different signals for the limits.

for example:

run nano with timeout sending SIGTERM after 5s and after 10s SIGKILL

Answer (score 0):

Program 'sleep' is the part of coreutils package.

Just execute this command in console:

```
man sleep
```

And you will find manual page about this program.

```
NAME
       sleep - delay for a specified amount of time

SYNOPSIS
       sleep NUMBER[SUFFIX]...
       sleep OPTION

DESCRIPTION
       Pause  for  NUMBER  seconds.   SUFFIX may be 's' for seconds (the default), 'm' for minutes, 'h' for hours or 'd' for days.  Unlike most implementations that require NUMBER be an integer, here
       NUMBER may be an arbitrary floating point number.  Given two or more arguments, pause for the amount of time specified by the sum of their values.

       --help display this help and exit

       --version
              output version information and exit

AUTHOR
       Written by Jim Meyering and Paul Eggert.
```